# jquery 1.5 problem with $.getJSON request to Vimeo

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an ajax-request to vimeo to get data from an vimeo video needed for our webapplication.

```
var vimeoDataUrl = "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/" + vimeoId; //+ "&callback=?";
console.log(vimeoDataUrl); //http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/16630327

$.getJSON(vimeoDataUrl, function (json, textStatus) {
    if (json != null) {
        var title = json.title;
        var videoWidth = json.width;
        var videoHeight = json.height;
        if (title != null && videoWidth != null && videoHeight != null) {

            var vimeoImageUrl = json.thumbnail_url;
            $('#largeImageUrl').val(vimeoImageUrl); 
            $('#videoName').val(title);
            $('#videoWidth').val(videoWidth);
            $('#videoHeight').val(videoHeight);
            hasValidVideoUrl = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //an message is shown
    }
    $('#videoName, #placeVideo').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('img#loading').remove();
 });
```

When I enter the vimeoDataUrl in an browser like IE i'm getting the json result as expected, but as soon as i'm looking at the request in firebug i'm getting an empty response with an 200-status. Can someone help me out here? Is the problem located at vimeo or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make json request to different domains ( [JS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).
You need to use **jsonp**

If you  un-comment the final part in your url, the `&callback=?` it works just fine .. because jquery will use jsonp if it finds it in the url.

so use

```
var vimeoDataUrl = "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/" + vimeoId + "&callback=?";
```

from the [`getJson`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

> **JSONP**
>
> If the URL includes the string
>   "***callback=?***" (or similar, as defined
>   by the server-side API), the request
>   is treated as **JSONP** instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in
>   $.ajax() for more details.
>
> **Additional Notes:**
>
> - Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are
>     subject to the same origin policy; the
>     request can not successfully retrieve
>     data from a different domain,
>     subdomain, or protocol.
> - Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy
>     restrictions.

**Demo at** http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/gQaXD/

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Will further investigate tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Also had to modify my ajaxSetup a bit. We made changes there when upgrading to jQuery 1.5. Resetting the jsonpcallback and adding the parameter fixed the problem.